# How do I stop a Binary Search Tree Traversal?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, recursion, data-structures, binary-search-tree

I need to traverse a binary search tree and return an array of the leaf nodes. At the moment I am traversing through the entire tree and returning one node at a time.

My tree looks like:

```
                 10. Captain Picard
                 /                  \
          6. Commander Riker       11. Commander Data
            /         \               \
    4. Lt. Cmdr.   7. Lt. Cmdr.     12. Lt. Cmdr.
        Worf           LaForge           Crusher
             \                           \
        5. Lieutenant                  13. Lieutenant
        security-officer                    Selar
```

So far I have:

```
  findOfficersWithNoDirectReports(values = []) {
    if (this.officerName === null) return;

    if (this.leftReport) {
      this.leftReport.findOfficersWithNoDirectReports(
        this.leftReport.officerName
      );
    }

    if (this.rightReport) {
      this.rightReport.findOfficersWithNoDirectReports(
        this.rightReport.officerName
      );
    }
    return values;
  }
```

My class constructor has: officerId, officerName, reportTo, LeftReport, rightReport. If I `console.log(this)` it looks like:

```
StarshipEnterprise {
  officerId: 10,
  officerName: 'Captain Picard',
  reportTo: null,
  leftReport: StarshipEnterprise {
    officerId: 6,
    officerName: 'Commander Riker',
    reportTo: [Circular],
    leftReport: StarshipEnterprise {
      officerId: 4,
      officerName: 'Lt. Cmdr. Worf',
      reportTo: [Circular],
      leftReport: null,
      rightReport: [StarshipEnterprise]
    },
    rightReport: StarshipEnterprise {
      officerId: 7,
      officerName: 'Lt. Cmdr. LaForge',
      reportTo: [Circular],
      leftReport: null,
      rightReport: null
    }
  },
  rightReport: StarshipEnterprise {
    officerId: 11,
    officerName: 'Commander Data',
    reportTo: [Circular],
    leftReport: null,
    rightReport: StarshipEnterprise {
      officerId: 12,
      officerName: 'Lt. Cmdr. Crusher',
      reportTo: [Circular],
      leftReport: null,
      rightReport: [StarshipEnterprise]
    }
  }
}
```

I should get:

```
["Lieutenant Security-Officer",
"Lt. Cmdr. LaForge",
"Lieutenant Selar"]
```

To return this array of leaf nodes, how do I stop my tree traversal when the `leftReport` and `rightReport` are `null`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
findOfficersWithNoDirectReports() {
    // If this is a leaf node, return the officer name
    if (!this.leftReport && !this.rightReport) {
      return [this.officerName]
    }

    // Otherwise, combine the left and right results 
    val result = []
    if (this.leftReport) {
      result = result.concat(this.leftReport.findOfficersWithNoDirectReports());
    }
    if (this.rightReport) {
      result = result.concat(this.rightReport.findOfficersWithNoDirectReports());
   }
    return result;

  }
```

Comment: Ahh I see. This makes way more sense. How do I put all three names into one array? I tried creating a new empty array and pushing this.officerName to it but still only get 1 name at a time

Comment: Oops sorry should be fixed now, needed to use the result of concat